# Up Vote after Down Vote === +2?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, voting

If I down vote an answer, that answer gets a -1. If I then up vote that same answer, the answer is now rated as 2. The down and subsequent up votes should cancel each other out giving the answer a net rating of 0, instead it's as if it received two up votes. This is just wrong.

I have enough rep. where I can click on a question rating and see how many up/down votes there have been. And, if I just continuously up/down vote an answer it goes straight from -1 to 2 back to -1 again, so I'm pretty confident that it is not another user voting at the same time as me.

Why does it work this way?

EDIT:

I will report this to SO and see what comes of it. I will update when I have more information.

UPDATED EDIT:

The answer in question is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785992/getting-text-from-a-forms-input-javascript/44786180?noredirect=1#comment76553449_44786180). It's the answer that starts with *"Do small Changes in your code"*

Comment: I'm not sure, but when you upvote or downvote, the vote count gets updated via AJAX/websockets/asynchronuous voodo. So in your situation, somebody might have given another upvote between you downvoting and upvoting the answer.

Comment: No. I have enough rep. where I can click on a question rating and see how many up/down votes there have been. And, if I just continuously up/down vote an answer it goes straight from -1 to 2 back to -1 again.

Comment: Also - you get only 1 vote per answer/question. So after you downvote, upvoting removes your downvote (changing score from -1 to 0) and applies your upvote (changing score from 0 to +1).

Comment: Why would an up vote after a down vote remove the down vote **and** apply an up vote? If that is the case, then there should be another option to simply retract your previous vote.

Comment: Huh. You should edit that in (ie. that you tested that thoroughly) to your question.

Comment: LOL And, now I'm down voted with no explanation. Nice.

Comment: Try refreshing the question. More than likely someone else also voted around the same time as you.

Comment: @ale As I said, I can click on the rating and see how many up/down votes there have been. When I change from down to an up, the vote goes from -1 to 2, which *could* indicate another vote at the same time as mine, but if I then go back to a down vote, the rating goes from 2 to -1.

Comment: @ScottMarcus What post was this on? (You don't need to do anything special to report this further - this is exactly what Meta is for.)

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted. This *might* be the behaviour the OP has observed. We need to give them the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @AdamLear I have updated the question with a link to the answer in question.

Answer (score 4):

For what's it worth, upvoting and downvoting this question and Steven Vascellaro's answer doesn't show this behaviour.

1. Upvoting for the first time changes post's score to +1.
2. Downvoting for the first time changes post's score to -1.
3. Upvoting after downvoting changes post's score from -1 to +1.
4. Downvoting after upvoting changes post's score from +1 to -1.
5. Retracting upvote/downvote (by click on up/down arrow second time) resets post's score back to 0.

Therefore, the behaviour you have described might be a bug. Perhaps you should point out to the question exhibiting this behaviour for further reproduction and testing?

Also, assuming that question is on Stack Overflow (since you have 15k reputation on it), well, [Stack Overflow *might* be experiencing technical difficulties at the moment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351346/logging-in-to-stack-overflow-doesnt-log-me-in-to-stack-exchange).

Comment: +1 for a nice explanation. I can't mark this as the answer at this point in time since it's still not known what the exact issue is. I will report to SO and see what they come up with. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also unable to reproduce this. When I click the up arrow after downvoting, the count shifts to 1. To be fair, I didn't quite go through all the setup to perfectly replicate the case... which is that there *is* another upvote on that answer that came before any of your votes (either up or down).

We do update the score both client-side and after the server comes back with a result. It does seem a bit weird that it went back to -1 for you instead of 0, but I'm reasonably confident that there's no bug here. When in doubt, refresh the page to get the "known-good" current score.

Comment: No, there were no other votes on the answer except mine. No previous votes.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, there were. I'm looking at the timestamps. :) IIRC we don't update vote counts live, so if you had the page open from before the vote was cast, you'd still see 0 for the score.

Comment: The other upvote came in about 3 minutes before you cast your first downvote.